# How to get images from link and use canvas to merges them in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, asynchronous, request

I wrote an api to get images from Google Streetview and I want to merge them into images.

api ex : http://gpano-14520981.rhcloud.com/json?zoom=5&lat=51.50700703827454&lng=-0.12791916931155356

param : zoom : 1 to 5
lat & lng are coordinates

I use request module inside forEach loop, but it is an async callback. So I cannot merge images.

```
// declare
forEach(data.images, function(image){
   request(image.url, ..., function(err,res,body){
      var img = new Canvas.Image();
      img.src = new Buffer(body,'binary');
      // canvas code process ...
   });
console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
});
```

Comment: I don't know any of the API you use, but if it is async, then use callbacks.

Comment: I use google api and I make my owner api.

Comment: It response columns: 26,
rows: 13,
tileWidth: 512,
tileHeight: 512,
width: 13312,
height: 6656, and Image objects.

Comment: Yes but still, if the `request` is asynchronous, then the `console.log(canvas.toDataURL());` is called before it has finished, and thus before anything is drawn onto it. So, use a callback and call it only when all your `request`s are done.

Comment: I know that. But I dont know change it. :)

Comment: I have tried many different ways but still are not.

Comment: Oh common you wrote an API... `function callback(){console.log...}; var current=0; forEach(foo, ... {if(current++===foo.length)callback()}`

Comment: I try use `httpsync` module but It doesn't work.

Comment: and `request.get(..)` inside `forEach` ?

Comment: if you need to make a `request()` for each of your foo, yes

Comment: getListofLinks -> getDataofImages -> forEach and merge -> show canvas.toDataURL() ->.. that operating procedures.

Comment: yes but call the  show canvas.toDataURL() only in the last instance of the async calls in the forEach

Comment: but I declare canvas in another function, not callback

Comment: https://gist.github.com/toanalien/1e6ac4a3690c9cd2fcf2 my code. please help